# FFT on MPU6050 output signal

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, fft, arduino-uno, mpu6050

I want to perform FFT on data array that I have extracted from MPU6050 sensor connected to Arduino UNO using Python

Please find the data sample below

> 0.13,0.04,1.03
>
> 0.14,0.01,1.02
>
> 0.15,-0.04,1.05
>
> 0.16,0.02,1.05
>
> 0.14,0.01,1.02
>
> 0.16,-0.03,1.04
>
> 0.15,-0.00,1.04
>
> 0.14,0.03,1.02
>
> 0.14,0.01,1.03
>
> 0.17,0.02,1.05
>
> 0.15,0.03,1.03
>
> 0.14,0.00,1.02
>
> 0.17,-0.02,1.05
>
> 0.16,0.01,1.04
>
> 0.14,0.02,1.01
>
> 0.15,0.00,1.03
>
> 0.16,0.03,1.05
>
> 0.11,0.03,1.01
>
> 0.15,-0.01,1.03
>
> 0.16,0.01,1.05
>
> 0.14,0.02,1.03
>
> 0.13,0.01,1.02
>
> 0.15,0.02,1.05
>
> 0.13,0.00,1.03
>
> 0.08,0.01,1.03
>
> 0.09,-0.01,1.03
>
> 0.09,-0.02,1.03
>
> 0.07,0.01,1.03
>
> 0.06,0.00,1.05
>
> 0.04,0.00,1.04
>
> 0.01,0.01,1.02
>
> 0.03,-0.05,1.02
>
> -0.03,-0.05,1.03
>
> -0.05,-0.02,1.02

I have taken 1st column (X axis) and saved in an array

Reference:https://hackaday.io/project/12109-open-source-fft-spectrum-analyzer/details 
from this i took a part of FFT and the code is as below

```
from scipy.signal import filtfilt, iirfilter, butter, lfilter
from scipy import fftpack, arange
import numpy as np
import string
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sample_rate = 0.2

accx_list_MPU=[]

outputfile1='C:/Users/Meena/Desktop/SensorData.txt'

def fftfunction(array):


    n=len(array)
    print('The length is....',n)
    k=arange(n)
    fs=sample_rate/1.0
    T=n/fs
    freq=k/T
    freq=freq[range(n//2)]
    Y = fftpack.fft(array)/n
    Y = Y[range(n//2)]
    pyl.plot(freq, abs(Y))
    pyl.grid()
    ply.show()
with open(outputfile1) as f:
                string1=f.readlines()
                N1=len(string1)

                for i in range (10,N1):
                    if (i%2==0):
                                new_list=string1[i].split(',')

                                l=len(new_list)
                                if (l==3):

                                        accx_list_MPU.append(float(new_list[0]))
fftfunction(accx_list_MPU)
```

I have got the output of FFT as shown [FFToutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb5ON.png)

I do not understand if the graph is correct.. This is the first time im working with FFT and how do we relate it to data

This is what i got after the changes suggested:[FFTnew](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVjsB.png)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am sorry,i edited it

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little rework of your `fftfunction`:

```
def fftfunction(array):
    N = len(array)
    amp_spec = abs(fftpack.fft(array)) / N
    freq = np.linspace(0, 1, num=N, endpoint=False)

    plt.plot(freq, amp_spec, "o-", markerfacecolor="none")
    plt.xlim(0, 0.6)  # easy way to hide datapoints
    plt.margins(0.05, 0.05)

    plt.xlabel("Frequency $f/f_{sample}$")
    plt.ylabel("Amplitude spectrum")
    plt.minorticks_on()
    plt.grid(True, which="both")

fftfunction(X)
```

Specifically it removes the `fs=sample_rate/1.0` part - shouldn't that be the inverse?

The plot then basically tells you how strong which frequency (relative to the sample frequency) was. Looking at your image, at `f=0` you have your signal offset or mean value, which is around 0.12. For the rest of it, there's not much going on, no peaks whatsoever that indicate a certain frequency being overly present in the measurement data.

Comment: I have tried to use the function as you suggested.. i got the graph as shown with the name FFTnew